# How to get the attribute value of xlink:title from xml

Tags: c#, xml, tridion, tridion-2011

This is my xml generated for retrieving members of a group. I need to get the value tech\abc1234 from this xml.

```
<tcm:Trustee xlink:href="tcm:0-61-65552" xlink:type="simple" xlink:title="tech\abc1234" Type="65552" Icon="T65552L0P0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"></tcm:Trustee>
```

But when i try to get the attribute value like:

```
XElement userList = csClient.GetListXml(grpId, members);

foreach (var eachuser in userList.Elements())
       {
            logdetails(eachuser.Attribute("xlink:title").Value.ToString());
       }
```

I am getting the following error :
    `error The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently, you're using the `string` to `XName` conversion, which takes that string as *just* the local ID of an element, and that can't contain a colon.

You need to create an `XName` with the full namespace + local ID. Fortunately, LINQ makes that really easy:

```
XNamespace xlink = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
XElement userList = csClient.GetListXml(grpId, members);

foreach (var user in userList.Elements())
{
    logdetails(user.Attribute(xlink + "title").Value);
}
```

Note that there's no need to call `ToString()` after `Value` - [`XAttribute.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.value.aspx) already returns a string.